# Without AuthMiddlewareStack how can I get logged user in Django channels?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-channels

Without AuthMiddlewareStack how can I get logged, user?
Because I am not used auth models that's why self.scope['user'] returning the 'Anonymous'.

I tried to add this class AllowedHostsOriginValidator - doesn't work.
I want a session user. please help me.

[image]

routing.py

```
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from django.urls import path
from chat.consumers import ChatConsumer
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.security.websocket import AllowedHostsOriginValidator

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
'websocket': AllowedHostsOriginValidator(
    AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter([
        path('ws/chat/pm-with/<str:username>/',ChatConsumer()),
        ])
    )
  )
})
```

consumers.py

```
from channels.consumer import SyncConsumer
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync
from chat.models import user,Thread,Message
from chat.views import ChatView
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session

class ChatConsumer(SyncConsumer):
    def websocket_connect(self,event):
        me = self.scope['user']
        other_user = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['username']
        getOtheruser = user.objects.filter(username = other_user).first()
        
        self.send({
            'type': 'websocket.accept',
        })
    
    def websocket_receive(self,event):
        print("new event is received")
        print(event)
        self.send({
            'type': 'websocket.send',
            'text': event.get('text'),
        })
        
    def websocket_disconnect(self,event):
        print("disconnect event is called")
```

custom user models

models.py

```
class user(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50,default="", blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50,default="", blank=True, null=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50,default="", blank=True, null=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100,default="", blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to ='user_image',default="",blank=True,null=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    deleted = models.DateTimeField(default="",blank=True, null=True)
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I want login users from custom models, not auth user models.
please help me for this